# Missing something when writing to a Text File

Tags: c#

I simply want to be able to log the path of certain files to a text file.
I have the following to do the logging.

```
static void LogFile(string lockedFilePath)
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string workingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ass.Location);
        string LogFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, "logFiles.txt");

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(LogFile))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(LogFile))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(lockedFilePath);   
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(LogFile))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(lockedFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but If I call it in a Console App like this

```
foreach (string f in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\AASource"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Logging : " + f);
                LogFile(f);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

The only file that is listed in the resulting text file is the last file in the dir.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `System.IO.File.OpenWrite(LogFile)`, use `System.IO.File.AppendText(LogFile)`. When you use `OpenWrite` you're going to be overwriting the contents with whatever you write in.

Additionally, your `if` statement (`if (!System.IO.File.Exists(LogFile))`) is not required. `AppendText` (and `OpenWrite`) for that matter will create the file if it doesn't exist. This means you can simply get away with running the code within the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in append mode. Otherwise, you delete everything that was in the file before.

[Here's the logfile code I use](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/a-convenient-logfile-class) if you'd like to see some other examples.

Answer (score 0):

File.AppendText [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the file each time you call the LogFile method.  You can use the overload for StreamWriter that allows for appending to the end of the file:

```
void LogFile(string lockedFilePath)
{
    Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string workingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ass.Location);
    string LogFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, "logFiles.txt");

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LogFile, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(lockedFilePath);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void LogFile(string lockedFilePath)
        {
            Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string workingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ass.Location);
            string LogFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingFolder, "logFiles.txt");

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LogFile, System.Environment.NewLine + lockedFilePath);

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should Flush and Close the StreamWriter. If only the last file is written there is that you'r just overwriting what you had.

See you.

Comment: This is not required, at the end of the `using` it is properly cleaned up and closed.